# jar file not working because of image

Tags: java, image, jar, executable-jar

I think my executable jar file is not working because the image I'm using is not being loaded. When I made a batch file and ran the jar it said

```
"IllegalArgumentException: input == null!"
```

The program works perfectly when I run it in eclipse. So my question is do you need to do something special with images in order to run a jar file correctly?

Code I think is causing the error:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Sprite.class.getResource(path));
this.width = image.getWidth();
this.height = image.getHeight();
this.pixels = new int[width * height];
image.getRGB(x, y, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
```

Edit: the program works fine (images load) in eclipse, it's just when I export it as an executable jar file that the program doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please provide some of your code?

Comment: path is wrong. Check similar questions to see what it should be.

Comment: I tried using the code from the similar question, but that made it so it loads the file as an Image, and java said it could not cast to a BufferedImage. Is there a way that I could make that turn into a BufferedImage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wants to know how I solved it:

I changed the

```
Sprite.class.getResource(path)
```

to

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)
```

and I moved the images to the same location as the jar. For example, I had both the jar (exported it to the desktop) and the images on the desktop, and the path was "/" plus the file name.